Motion tracking with bad footage
I've been trying to work on a shot that was not meant for 3D at first, just trying to add a few 3D objects inside. I made that before on other shots and got results I'm happy with, but this one is hard. I manage to get more than 8 tracking points, either manually placed or automatically detected, and can get a solve error below 0.6, but the end result is always off, even the best looking one make the object look like they are sliding. I think this is partly due to the footage defaults :

It's at night, so quite dark above ground
It gets blurry when there is movement and focus is overall not very sharp
It has a panoramic movement in the middle (around 80° rotation) but was not made with a tripod (it was a monopod, so it's not very steady but it's also not moving that much)

To my understanding, this last point may be the worst, since both tripod and classic solve algorithm will be confused, either by the amount or the lack of movement around the origin of the camera.
My questions are :

Is there anything to do for footages that simply rotate without being on a tripod, or is it correct from me to assume this makes the whole thing impossible ? Is there a better solve algorithm in those cases, or does it entirely depends on the footage ?
Is it common to get solve error below 0.6 and still having most points clearly off in the camera view ?
Is there something that seems awfully off in my workflow ?

(Edit : here is a link to the video on youtube, sorry for delay)
Here are some additional details :

It's a cobbled sidewalk lit by street lighting, so there are some details to track.
Only a few details are visible through the whole clip (maybe 3-4 trackers), but I think it does not really matter
The panoramic part is clearly the one with the most erratic tracking, it's also the one where it gets the most blurry and where the monopod moved the most
Something that confuses me is that when I place points by hand, I follow them through both the track reprojection on the n-tab and the main view locked on the point position, so in both case I can see how much steady they are : it's quite good, I've managed to get correct camera movement with worse trackers before. And even with a solve error around 0.6, trackers in the 3D layout are way off the objects they have been tracking.
I think I tried to use most of the parameters of motion tracking in Blender, and that I mostly understand them. I checked all points from the great answer to this other question (appart from those about the original footage).
I tried various methods (either tracking point by point manually, auto-detecteting features and selecting only the correct looking ones, spamming as many trackers as I can get, and then cutting through those with few frames or big errors), with various motion model (Loc, Loc+Rot+Sca, Perspective), with between 3 and 10 iterations each time to erase tracks with big error and retrack some when this leads to a lack of tracks at some point (yellow/red areas in the timeline). I also tracked with different sizes (from 30 to 100 pixels).
I used both Keyframe and Previous Frame matching, everytime with Prepass enabled. I tried with Normalize but it does not change much, and since lighting is stable through the clip I don't think it matters. Tried limiting to Red color channel, since it's where contrast is at its most but appart tracking speed improvements I didn't notice much.
I don't know the focal length used, I let Blender guess most of the time. I tried with various combination of Focal Length / Optical Center / Distortion either defined or refined, but it did not change much either. Some Focal Length give better solve error (around 30mm and around 150mm), but the points are still off in the end.

Here is the last frame of the clip, to give an idea :

To illustrate my interrogations on the relation between solve error and actual offset, here is an example : the overall solve error is 0.57, both point have an average error of 0.42 and 0.41, and we are on the part with the least error according to the blue curve. Both points are tracking the little white dots below them :

Note : this is my first question here, so please point out if there is anything wrong.

It would help to see the footage (youtube ? no solution here sadly). I'd say your focal length is either 28mm or 35mm for a full frame sensor, I don't know what device you use. You don't want to use tripod solving if not on tripod, for sure.

@Lutzi it was a camcorder, Sony AX53, so no precise objective focal length. It varies between 26 and around 530mm (for a 36mm sensor), though I'm not sure if those are only optical or if the digital zoom is included as well. There's no way to get it back from metadata, and I do not know if it was shot was zoomed in a bit, a lot or at all. I'll  look into a solution to share the footage. Thanks for the info on the tripod solving, I'll stay away from it for this one.
(Also updated the title, thanks for pointing it out !)

Not sure what the question is about. More and more accurate tracking points will probably improve the situation(try 50 instead of 8), if it has stabilization or digital zoom, that's probably going to be a problem, but that's something obvious. If you wanted help with specific situation, without seeing the whole footage people are not going to be able to advise.

You ultimately only need 3 well-tracked points on a surface to do a planar track, whats stopping you from just manually adding three points to some of those high contrast white dots on the ground there, moving through every 5-15 frames or so and adjust them individually until you've got it tracked. Don't get too caught up in the technical details of trying to fine tune the Blender auto-tracking features to do it all for you. Sometimes just brute forcing it is the simpler option. Doing it 50x a week, not so much. but for one shot it's probably fine to spend 30mins grinding it out.

Added a link to the footage on youtube so you can see it.
@MartynasŽiemys I had 20-30 points when manually tracking, and 80-150 when auto tracking. You are right, the more tracks I get, the better the error solve is, but it still feels like sliding around.

@Jakemoyo I'm not sure if you mean tracking the dots in motion tracking tab, or adding points in 3D world and aligning camera myself. If it's the 1st option, Blender tracks them very well already. I don't think I could get a better result. The problem comes when applying the "correct" tracking to the 3D camera, then the reprojected trackers are off from the camera's background movie clip. If it's the 2nd option, I could try that, thanks !

There is very little movement to solve the camera parameters from, so any slightest error in tracking is going to be a problem. I would make as many markers as possible and make sure every single one is perfectly tracked, adjusting frame by frame if needed and removing anything less than absolutely pixel perfect and then just hope for the best. If it works it works, if doesn't it doesn't - like you said, it's bad footage for this. It's not that the footage itself is the worst, it's bad that you know nothing about the camera.

@MartynasŽiemys OK, thank you very much for your answer. It could be a solution, I never had exclusively perfect trackers, I often included some that "looked steady" but may not be pixel-perfect steady. I'll try this !

I'm not sure if this helps in this case but you could try to make an object track instead of a camera track. the process is the same, you just have to enter that you want an object track before tracking (https://youtu.be/grclmlKzwY4?si=Ng-tgDv4KUPmwCr0). You could choose the Ground as the Object.

I had to track some very blurry shots before and In general large trackers work the best in these scenarios. Always remember that only the centre of the track is actually important, blender does not care if the feature is otherwise nicely tracked as long as the centre stays on target. This is one of the best tutorials/demonstration I saw of this *technique" (https://youtu.be/g8uVZYFIKJA?si=kwtVPYwxNZa0wnVd)

To keep this up to date, Martynas and Marius' comments put me on a good way. I managed to get a tracking I'm happy with by both (1) being very rigorous with the tracker placement (both by checking myself for misplacement, and setting a higher correlation, around .85) and (2) using much bigger tracks (50-200px), which helped both the autotrack and myself identifying patterns.
I didn't know about the object tracking, I'll keep that in mind. I already saw the blurry tracking video but am dumb enough to forget about it, thanks for the reminder !
And thanks everyone for your good advices <3
